# Skin is pulled to one side - using X-Muscle in Blender 2.8

Tags: python, mesh, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

[image: skin pulls to one side]

Hi!

I am creating my first Blender-Model, using the add-on "[X-Muscle-System](https://blendermarket.com/products/x-muscle-system)" in Blender 2.8.

I don´t know how to solve the "yellow" issue: The skin is pulled too much to one side (when moving the armature to this position).
I think I need to renew the weights in weight painting.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how I should change them without getting hard cuts and how to make it smooth, respectively, do I have to expand or limit the tibia-vertex group and do I have to set the value closer to 1 or closer to 0?

Would it work better by using Python in Blender?

Can anyone help me, please?

Further information:

I am using the Blender add-on called "[X-Muscle-System](https://blendermarket.com/products/x-muscle-system)" this works fine. I created Micro-Controllers and now set the "skin tension" to Zero. Therefore, this is not influencing the Skin anymore.

Comment: Could you ever solve this issue?